# Python: Azure Storage table failed to insert batch items when they are exists

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I using Azure storage table with python and try to insert batch of entities. When inserting an entity for the first time, when it's not exists on table, it's working fast (as expected). On the second time to insert the same entity, the code is just stuck for a minute and nothing really happend.

### The code

This is my batch insert:

```
acc_name = 'AccountName'
    acc_key = 'MyKey'
    table_name='MyTable'

    service = TableService(account_name=acc_name, account_key=acc_key)
    batch = TableBatch()
    batch.insert_entity({
        'PartitionKey': 'PARTITION1',
        'RowKey': "1",
        'someKey': 'key'
    })

    service.commit_batch(table_name, batch)
```

Just try to run this code twice. First time it will work, on the second time it's stuck for a minute with and return the error:

```
Client-Request-ID=a734f002-7dff-11e8-b587-28c63f6cb636 Retry policy did not allow for a retry: Server-Timestamp=Mon, 02 Jul 2018 13:55:29 GMT, Server-Request-ID=4168269a-0002-0073-640c-121de2000000, HTTP status code=202, 
Exception=The specified entity already exists.RequestId:4168269a-0002-0073-640c-121de2000000Time:2018-07-02T13:55:30.4994452Z.
```

### Test #1

I'm pretty sure that this is not planned behavior since when I running the equivalent code in C#, it's throw an exception immediately: "Element in index 0 is already exists.". Which is make sense...

### Test #2

Another test I made is to insert an entity, not in batch. In this case, when the entity already in the table, it's just throw "Already exists" exception. Which is good.

### My environment

Windows 10, Python 3.6 (64 bit), azure-sdk for python (version 3.0.0).

Someone can confirm this behavior? What to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. `insert_entity` operation is a wrapper over [`Insert Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity) REST API operation which creates an entity if it does not exists otherwise fails with `409 (Conflict)` error. Again because an operation in batch fails, the whole batch operation fails.

You should try using `Upsert` operations. You can either use [`Insert or Replace Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-replace-entity) or [`Insert or Merge Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-merge-entity). These operations will ensure that an entity is either created (if not exists) or updated (if exists). Corresponding operations in Python SDK should be `insert_or_replace_entity` and `insert_or_merge_entity` respectively.

Comment: `Upsert` methods will change the existing row which unwanted. When batch insert fails bacause the entity is already exists, it should specify the first item that fail to insert. Expected message: `0:The specified entity already exists.`. I cant find any reason why this non-harmful function should take 60 seconds to be executed (insert a row, the table is contains only one row). For me it's seems like a bug. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682971/azure-storage-table-insert-batch-of-row-and-check-if-they-exists

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Gaurav Mantri simply replace insert_entity with insert_or_merge_entity:

```py
acc_name = 'AccountName'
acc_key = 'MyKey'
table_name='MyTable'

service = TableService(account_name=acc_name, 
                       account_key=acc_key)
batch = TableBatch()
batch.insert_or_merge_entity({
    'PartitionKey': 'PARTITION1',
    'RowKey': "1",
    'someKey': 'key'
    })

service.commit_batch(table_name, batch)
```